# SQL Count group by days

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift

I'm interested in looking at the different lengths its takes to get a package delivered from some example data. I'm currently using this code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM orders_table
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, order_date, delivered_date) = 2
AND order_date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31'
```

I want to get counts of deliveries that take different lengths, in the example above it looks at the number of deliveries that take 2 days. However this is quite time consuming as I need to keep changing the where statement for a different number of days and rerunning the code, would there be a way to sort of group it and also group on the month? So that the output would look like this:

```
January           February           March              April
2D   3D   4D      2D   3D   4D       2D   3D   4D      2D   3D   4D 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
12   7    32      21   53   33       8    22   41      9    44   30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not exactly provide output in your desired format, but the results seem exactly what you want.
Do a group by the DATEDIFF function:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, order_date, delivered_date) AS Date_Diff, COUNT(*)
FROM orders_table
WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31'
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(day, order_date, delivered_date)
```

In case you want only the particular datediff days (like, if you want to see the orders with only 2, 3 and 4 days of difference of order and delivered dates), then just add your desired numbers in the filter:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, order_date, delivered_date) IN (2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question includes the month.  For that:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', order_date) as yyyymm
       DATEDIFF(day, order_date, delivered_date) as days_diff,
       COUNT(*)
FROM orders_table
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('month', order_date), DATEDIFF(day, order_date, delivered_date);
```

You can pivot these results using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, order_date, delivered_date) as days_diff,
       SUM( (DATE_PART(month, order_date) = 1)::INT ) as jan,
       SUM( (DATE_PART(month, order_date) = 2)::INT ) as feb,
       SUM( (DATE_PART(month, order_date) = 3)::INT ) as mar,
       SUM( (DATE_PART(month, order_date) = 4)::INT ) as apr
       COUNT(*)
FROM orders_table
WHERE order_date >= '2021-01-01' AND
      order_date < '2021-05-01'
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(day, order_date, delivered_date);
```